# how to show linked in share button using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

i am showing the linked in share button using this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://www.example.com"></script>
```

The share button is displaying and working as it should, but when i am loading more content by ajax, share button is not displaying, just this 2 scripts are there. I searched their API but couldn't find any way. Is there any way we can call for share button by any javascript or jquery function?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i finally found it myself, this is how we can do it :

```
$.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=false", function success() {
    IN.init({
      api_key: "API KEY HERE"
    });
  });
```

Comment: You still need to include the button in the HTML to place your button

``<script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://www.example.com"></script>``